# Show by hand $\int_{0}^{1}\cot\left(e^{-x^{2}}\right)!dx<\int_{0}^{1}x^{-x}dx$

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, gamma-function

### Problem :

Show that :

$$\int_{0}^{1}\Gamma\left(\cot\left(e^{-x^{2}}\right)+1\right)dx<\int_{0}^{1}x^{-x}dx$$

---

---

I use Desmos notation .

In hoping to show it by hand I have tried the Sophomore dream :

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{-x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-n}$$

I cannot find a power series for the other side .

For information we need to show :

$$1.29125<1.29128$$

Wich looks very hard at first glance but a also a very challenging problem .

---

---

Some remarks :

Let $0<x<1$ then it seems the $n$ th derivative is strictly positive or :

$$f^{(n)}(x)>0$$

Where :

$$f(x)=\Gamma\left(\cot\left(e^{-x^{2}}\right)+1\right)$$

Wich says (and again it seems) if the power series exists then the coefficients are strictly positives .Moreover around zero it seems there is only the even derivatives wich seems to increase exponentialy .

As point out by ClaudeLeibovici the conjecture is false but it seems true as power series around $x=1$

---

---

---

Any ideas to show it without any calculator so by hand  ?

Comment: Gamma function for the factorial ?

Comment: Same question as Hamdiken : what is the meaning of excalamation point ?

Comment: The $!$ notation is typically defined for nonnegative integers. What does it mean to take the factorial of a function? Do you use the Gamma Function?

Comment: @Accelerator Yes see my edit I think now it's not confusing .

Comment: This is rather easy. Just get a lower bound on the RHS akin to the numerics you got (e.g. via Riemann Sums or sophmore's dream or whatever else via positivity) and then expand the LHS as a power series to enough terms and use some form of the remainder (e.g. Lagrange) to show the result plus the error is less than the lower bound for the RHS

Answer (score 0):

If we expand $f(x)$ as a series$$f(x)=\Gamma\Big[\cot\left(e^{-x^{2}}\right)+1\Big]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,x^{2n}$$ the coefficient are **not** all positive
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & a_n \\
 0 & +0.898944 \\
 1 & +0.205125 \\
 2 & +0.796432 \\
 3 & +0.166882 \\
 4 & +0.779911 \\
 5 & -0.144472 & \text{negative}\\
 6 & +0.782758 \\
 7 & -0.480548  & \text{negative}\\
 8 & +0.89023 \\
  9 & -0.833327  & \text{negative}\\
 10 & +1.130030 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Can you elaborate how this proves the desired inequality $\int_{0}^{1}\Gamma\left(\cot\left(e^{-x^{2}}\right)+1\right)dx<\int_{0}^{1}x^{-x}dx$ ?

Comment: @MartinR. Where did I say that ?  This is a comment after reading in the post *" then the coefficients are strictly positive"*

Comment: Hello Claude I easy recognize this is false what can we say around $x=1$ ? (+1)

Comment: @ErikSatie. Guess what ? This is what I am working on. Cheers :-)